# Does OAuth2 for Google's API need each user to be signed in Google?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm not understanding how OAuth2 works for Google API.

Supposing I've signed in API's console and chosen several API's I would like to use.
My website should offers these API's to its users.

I have a doubt if my website users have to be logged in GOOGLE to can use these APIs.

For example, some users that prefer to login with Facebook couldn't use the APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User must be signed in Google to grant authorization to your application.

Your application is required to provide an access token when call Google API. The access token is granted by a Google user so that your application is able to access this user's resource on Google. So it's obvious that the user must be signed in Google.

Comment: Make sense! So, if a user logs with Facebook, we won't be able to use google's APIs... Thanks dude

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the API. Anything where you're accessing a user's data on their behalf (tasks, calendar, etc) then of course the user would need to have a Google account and would need to log in when authorizing your app.

But not all APIs act on user data. APIs like search & translate don't require a user to authorize access, and typically use a simple API key rather than OAuth.

Comment: True. But I think the question is focusing on OAuth.